# sharepoint 2013 custom error page

Tags: sharepoint

for one Sharepoint 2013 site, I successfully managed to create a custom 404 error page by setting the site parameter `vti_filenotfoundpage` to the desired URL.

However, this **does not work** for another sharepoint 2013 site and I have no clue why.

Setting the same parameter shows now effect.
Also setting another parameter `SPSite.FileNotFoundUrl` doesnt do it.

Apparently I am not able to add the 'error page' to the content type: For the parent content type "Publishing Content Types" or "Page Layout Content Types" I can only select other options.

How can I map the error page (which is non-existent at the moment) to a custom page? Thanks!

***edit:***
I assume to have a 15 Hive site (as the site settings URL contains .../_layout/15/...)

I created various files but none of them works (CustomError.aspx, PageNotFoundError.aspx as well as in Site Pages as in the site root directory).

I have site owner and designer rights (but no admin/collection).
And I am working on a sub site (have only rights to this sub site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible for sub sites, only via main site

Answer (score 0):

Plase see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154480/how-to-create-custom-error-page-in-sharepoint-2013 - it is original answer and you can find other solutions here.

As mentioned in linked topic: "Using SharePoint Designer 2013 (set `vti_filenotfoundpage` property) – With the new Site Options in `SharePoint Designer 2013`, you can assign the `vti_filenotfoundpage` property of the site to a Custom Error Page that you might have deployed in the 15 Hive. ",  - that means you can only use error page from **current** site's 15 Hive, not from other site.

Comment: Thanks... I have no idea if the existing site is/has the "15 hive". How can I find this out? And if not, is there still a way to customize the error pages?

Comment: btw: I have designer/owner rights but not admin, if this is relevant?

Comment: You only need to create such a page on the other site and set the appropriate url.

Comment: I created PageNotFoundError.aspx in the Site Pages but it doesn't work. What do you mean by 'set the appropriate url'? I already tried to set the website parameter but it doesn't work either. :-(

Comment: I also created 'CustomError.aspx' in the main site directory, but that doesn't do it either.

Comment: as the URL sometimes says .../_layout/15/... I assume that it is a 15 hive sharepoint site?!

Comment: Custom error pages (as well as default) are stored at the root site - all the sub-sites will inherit this error page (in fact, when you enter invalid url in browser address bar, SharePoint does not try to recognize which site of the site collection you tried to access - it will navigate to 15 hive of the root site collection's site). That is a rule: one site collection - one error page for all the subsites.

But you can make custom redirection by parsing "requestUrl" parameter at the site's error page and then redirect user to any page you want by javascript.

Comment: So that is a needed approach: create custom error page on the root site then add code to script editor on this page to parse "requestUrl" parameter in address bar, and redirect to needed page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if I only have access to the sub-site, there is no way to achieve it?